# Hacker Rank test errors on .count

Tags: javascript, count

I'm taking a hackerrank test that is a simple puzzle that states that 8=2 and 0,4,6,9 = 1 and all other numbers are equal to 0. So I wrote this function in javascript, and it works in ie out of notepad, but when I put it into the hackerrank console I get an error that points to the .count. Does anyone know why this would happen? I'm new to javascript so it maybe be a simple I just can't figure it out. Any help would be great. Thanks

```
var str = prompt("Number: ");
String.prototype.count = function(match) {
var res = this.match(new RegExp(match,"g"));
if (res==null) { return 0; }
return res.length;}
document.write((str.count(8)*2)+ str.count(4) + str.count(6) + str.count(9)      + str.count(0));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. Maybe a switch is in order:

```
function pickANumber(num){
  switch(num){
    case 8:
      return 2;
    case 0: case 4: case 6: case 9:
      return 1;
    default:
      return 0;
  }
}
console.log(pickANumber(8));
console.log(pickANumber(5));
console.log(pickANumber(9));
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of using switch. I'm not really sure what the error was, beyond the console error finder highlighted the usage of count, which I didn't think would be an issue. I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally frowned upon to prototype built-in objects like String or Array. It would be much easier to just define a standalone function that did the exact same thing, and you shouldn't have to worry about count not being defined. The problem might be that Hacker Rank isn't letting you modify the String object? Not sure about that though. Try using something like this:

```
function count(str, letter) { 
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think about that aspect. I know I have had issues in the past with their system, primarly because I'm newer to coding. Thanks for the advice. I'll remember that for the future.